# Microsoft Sync Framework File Synchronization how to detect changes from both sides but sync one way

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

Is it possible to Sync Files only in one way but detecting the changes on both sides.

So If the destination File is changed, the next sync should overwrite the file.

Answer (score 1):

ootb, no.

by default it will only send changes detected at the source. if the source and target were both changed, then you get a conflict which you can resolve by overwriting the destination. if only source wasnt change, it wont send the file, irregardless of whether the destination is changed or not.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want is to mirror a set of files. If you can use windows file sharing between your source and destination, robocopy would be an excellent solution for you. Robocopy is a utility built into windows. has a mirror option that would probably do what you want fairly easily (the `/MIR` switch). This will reset the destination to match the source no matter what changes have occurred on the destination.

Here is a [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx) that should get you started looking into robocopy.

Answer (score 0):

One way around this would be to use the sync framework to check if there are changes, but to use a different method (like WCF) to move the content from server to client. This would mean you could detect changes at both ends, and then use event handlers to create a list of files that you want to send across